# Is it possible to create indexes on a temp table when using SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, select-into

I am loading data from a CSV file into a temp staging table and this temp table is being queried a lot. I looked at my execution plan and saw that a lot of the time is spent scanning the temp table.

Is there any way to create index on this table when I `SELECT INTO` it?

```
SELECT *    
FROM TradeTable.staging.Security s
WHERE (
    s.Identifier IS NOT NULL
    OR s.ConstituentTicker IS NOT NULL
    OR s.CompositeTicker IS NOT NULL
    OR s.CUSIP IS NOT NULL
    OR s.ISIN IS NOT NULL
    OR s.SEDOL IS NOT NULL
    OR s.eSignalTicker IS NOT NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you cannot create a table and use select into to insert into it.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It's a heap table - so I would need to add a column for PK then?

Comment: Have you tried running a create index statement as the next statement in the batch?

Comment: @HLGEM It looks like the way I will solve this is 1) Create the temp table with `CREATE TABLE` and PK/Identity column and then 2) perform `INSERT` for all data. I can add indexes between 1) and 2).

Comment: Yes insert is for existing table (permanent or temp) so you can create index.  Select into is creates the table with no indexes.

Comment: I know it wasn’t specified, but if you are creating a clustered index, the best route is to use `CREATE TABLE #t` (even though it requires repeating one’s self) because the `INSERT INTO #t SELECT` will [insert the data in the right order in the most efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029695/429091). Creating the index after the fact will cause more work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The table created by `SELECT INTO` is always a heap. If you want a PK/Identity column you can either do as you suggest in the comments

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
/*Other Columns*/
)

INSERT INTO #T 
SELECT *
FROM TradeTable.staging.Security
```

Or avoid the explicit `CREATE` and need to list all columns out with

```
SELECT TOP (0) IDENTITY(int,1,1) As Id, *
INTO #T
FROM TradeTable.staging.Security

ALTER TABLE #T ADD PRIMARY KEY(Id)

INSERT INTO #T 
SELECT *
FROM TradeTable.staging.Security
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to `SELECT INTO`. `SELECT INTO` triggers the bulk insert optimisation. If you want the equivalent of that, then your `INSERT INTO` needs a `WITH (TABLOCK)`.